# How to make setters that return a new instance of the class in C#? (for making objects immutable)

Tags: c#, immutability

I have a class with several attributes that have getters and setters. I want to make the objects of this class immutable. I thought of giving the setters a return type instead of void like is done to the functions in *System.Collections.Immutable* classes. For now I did it like this:

```
MyImmutableClass
{
    public int MyAttribute { get; }
    public MyImmutableClass SetMyAttribute(int attribute)
    {
        return new MyImmutableClass(attribute, ...);
    }

    ...

    public MyImmutableClass(int attribute, ...)
    {
        MyAttribute = attribute;
        ...
    }
}
```

Is this how it should be done or is there a better/nicer way? Can I moddify a normal setter for instance?

Comment: Why do you want to have a setter in an immutable class? The cleanest way is to avoid any methods that change the state semantically, and explicitly design by contract, with having only getters. For "modification" you could create another class explicitly, using the Builder or Prototype design patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rather use a static factory method and use a private constructor, properties aren't made for this (because creating an object *may* be a lot of work -> use a method). You do everything in the create method, which gives you back an object that you **can't** modify anymore, by having readonly properties like you do:

```
public class MyImmutableClass
{
   public int MyAttribute { get; }

   private MyImmutableClass(int attribute, ...)
   {
       MyAttribute = attribute;
       ...
   }

   public static MyImmutableClass Create(int attribute)
   {
       return new MyImmutableClass(attribute, ...);
   }
}
```

Then use it:

```
var myClass = MyImmutableClass.Create(2);
```